# How to count string occurences in a list(Of String)

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to dynamically count from a list, how many times items have occured.  I can do it below if I specify the value I am looking for, but what I am really looking to do is to iterate through my list, count occurences, and total them out. My current code is below:

```
Dim itemlist As New List(Of String)
itemlist.add("VALUE1")
itemlist.add("VALUE2")
itemlist.add("VALUE3")


    Dim count As Integer = 0

    For Each value In itemlist

        If value.Equals("VALUE1") Then count += 1

    Next

 Msgbox(count.tostring)
```

So my point would be instead of searching for the value, let the app total them up and display the counted occurences it to the user, similar to a "COUNTIF" in excel.  I cant find much on this without using LINQ, Thanks

Comment: So you don't want to use LINQ or a for loop. What are you looking for? Could you provide a sample output?

Comment: Dim count = itemlist.Where(Function(s) s = "VALUE1").Count

Comment: I could use linq, I just figured there would be a simple way using lists to count duplicates. For example, if my list contained "RED", "RED", "RED", "GREEN",  It would output RED - 3, GREEN - 1

Comment: There **is** a simple way, use LINQ ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this very easily with LINQ:

```
Msgbox(itemlist.Where(Function(value) value = "VALUE1").Count)
```

To count duplicates, once again it's easy with LINQ:

```
Dim itemlist As New List(Of String)
itemlist.Add("RED")
itemlist.Add("RED")
itemlist.Add("RED")
itemlist.Add("GREEN")

dim groups = itemList.GroupBy(Function(value) value)

For Each grp In groups
    Console.WriteLine(grp(0) & " - " & grp.Count )
Next
```

Output:

```
RED - 3
GREEN - 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I intend however to populate based on whats occuring in the list.  For example, Lets say my list generates "RED", "RED", "RED", "BLUE".  I want to display the occurence value as "RED" - 3, "BLUE" - 1.  But what if "GREEN" shows up in the list?  I would like to just populate each uniquely and then count the duplicates instead of searching for a set value